# Pen Testing for REST API

Tags: open-source, security, automation, software-testing, rest

I am new to security testing. I have been able to set things up for web applications. I want to run automated scans for my REST API. Burpsuite is a good tool but is not free. Are there any open source tools available for REST?

Secondly, I have worked on SPOCK framework for automated API testing (using Groovy). Is there any way Spock can be used for such purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The free alternative that you can look at is [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org).

For broadly understood security testing I'd consider a stack (eg. consisting of [w3af](http://w3af.org), [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org)) rather than one single thing.

SPOCK supports some concepts like DDT (generally speaking it allows you to provide a set of inputs and verifiable outputs to ensure that application performs as expected with a certain range of data) and that may help indicating potential vulnerabilities, but have in mind that specific methodologies can be applied to a specific case.